# Valgrind permission denied on file

Tags: ubuntu, valgrind

I am running  Ubuntu 12.04 and installed Valgrind configure and installed it.
Everytime i run valgrind ./ file I always get permission denied even under root.

Comment: what are the file permissions? does it have executable bit on?
to force the executable bit, do this: chmod a+x ./file

Answer (score 12):

turn on the executable bit and then retry:

```
chmod a+x ./file
```

it is a safety feature to disallow executing just about any file by default.
and be very careful with unknown files in your root account.